# Circuitikz 'parallel' logic gate wiring

Tags: circuitikz

So I'm trying to draw the following circuit (Which looks like a half adder) using circuitikz.

[image: correct non-overlapping inputs]

However, my code is producing the below diagram.

[image: Overlapping inputs to second logic gate]

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0, 4)node[xor port] (xorone){}
(0, 2)node[and port] (and){}
(xorone.in 1) node[left=0.5cm](a) {A}
(xorone.in 2) node[left=0.5cm](b) {B}

(a) -| (xorone.in 1)
(b) -| (xorone.in 2)
(a) -| (and.in 1)
(b) -| (and.in 2);  
\end{circuitikz}
```

Is there any way I can make the two wires connecting the gates in 'parallel' not overlap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually one adds branch points where wires connect, either with  `to[short,o-*]` or `node[circ]` and `node[ocirc]`.  I specified point `(branch)` midway between `(b.east)` and `(xorone.in 2)`.

Note: circuitikz always loads the calc library.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0, 4)node[xor port] (xorone){}
(0, 2)node[and port] (and){}
(xorone.in 1) node[left=0.5cm](a) {A}
(xorone.in 2) node[left=0.5cm](b) {B}

(a.east) to[short,-*] (xorone.in 1) |- (and.in 1)
(b.east) to[short,-*] ($(b.east)!.5!(xorone.in 2)$) coordinate (branch)
    -- (xorone.in 2)
(branch) |- (and.in 2);  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]